# The first item of ComboBox is not selectable

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am using a `ComboBox` in my Windows application to allow a user to select time.

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="timePeriodComboBox"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
          Width="200" Height="60"
          FontSize="30"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Grid.Column="2">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

C#

```
#region Initializing Frequency Combo Box

timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("1 hour");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("2 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("5 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("10 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("15 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("20 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("24 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("48 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("72 hours");
timePeriodComboBox.Items.Add("96 hours");

timePeriodComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

timePeriodComboBox.SelectionChanged += timePeriodComboBox_indexChanged;

#endregion
historyRequestModel.time = timePeriodComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
```

The problem is when I run the application on a HP windows tablet it does not allow me to even touch the first item (as in it is not clickable or selectable or even highlight whilst the others do) on my list (1 hour).
However it works correctly when I run the emulator or simulator on visual studios. But the other items are selectable.

Can someone tell me what is wrong and if I have done something wrong or is this a bug? To be honest I think the problem could be the local machine uses a mouse and clicking as interactions where as the tablet uses touch screen as interaction. This is just a guess but I had a similar issue with the carousel version of the combobox. It worked fine on the local machine but then on the tablet it kept duplicating the values. So that is why I turned the carousel off. Any ideas?

Comment: Please define "cannot select" and show the `timePeriodComboBox_indexChanged` event handler.

Comment: I copied your code into a new solution and it works perfectly well.

Comment: It looks like you can select the first item no problem, (e.g., `timePeriodComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0`).  If you were unable to "Select" this item then you would have some sort of compilation error.  It would think CodeCaster's comment is the one that matters, show your `indexChanged` event.

Comment: @user3929914 where is the `timePeriodComboBox_indexChanged` implementation? Show it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to touch events and for example translate the touches to whatever suits your needs.

[Touch and Manipulation (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010(v=vs.110).aspx#touch_and_manipulation)

> The base classes, UIElement, UIElement3D, and ContentElement, define events that you can subscribe to so your application will respond to touch. Touch events are useful when your application interprets touch as something other than manipulating an object. For example, an application that enables a user to draw with one or more fingers would subscribe to touch events.

some more usefull links:

[Why won't WPF controls work with manipulations?](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html)

[UIElement.CaptureTouch Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturetouch(v=vs.110).aspx)

[UIElement.ReleaseTouchCapture Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.releasetouchcapture(v=vs.110).aspx)